# How do I change the color of the icon at the left of a file tab in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The red round icon pointed out by the red arrow bothers me.

[image]

I've tried all the themes shipped with vs code and some other extensions, none of them changes the color of that annoying icon.

How do I change the color of it or change the icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, the .java files have a coffee cup. My icon theme is [VSCode Icons](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscode-icons-team.vscode-icons).[image: vscode-icons]

Answer (score 1):

You have tried everything but have not found any way of doing it
through the user interface of VS Code.

There is left the strong-arm method, which is the editing of the
executable file of VS Code.

You will need to run a resource editor, use it to open the
executable file, find the icon, extract it to a file,
then edit it to change its color,
and finally replace it in the executable.

You will need to repeat the operation any time that you install an update that replaces the VS Code executable, so better note the
identifier of this icon resource, for future repetitions.

A couple of known freeware tools for editing resource files are:

- [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/)
- [Risoh Editor](https://katahiromz.web.fc2.com/re/en/)

A good icon editor is the free
[Greenfish Icon Editor Pro](http://greenfishsoftware.org/gfie.php#apage).